# Como fazer um form ficar centralizado em um figure

Tags: css

Tenho um `figure` e em seu interior um `form`, o grande problema é que quando redimensiono o navegador o figure se reajusta perfeitamente, porém o `form` que está em seu interior sai fora do objeto.

A imagem abaixo exibe seu está normal, com o navegador maximizado.

**OBS:** O `figure` exibe a foto e o `form` é o retângulo preto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao reajustar o navegador o `form` sai do espaço centralizado do `figure`, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o `form` fique sempre centralizado no meio do `figure`.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="cx-fotos-portugal">
    <form>

    </form>
    <img src="./fotos-portugal/foto-portugal-capitania-do-porto-cascais.jpg">
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure.cx-fotos-portugal img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 550px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form{
    position: absolute;
    width: 35.71428571428571%;
    height: 14.28571428571429%;
    max-height: 550px;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 35%;
    top: 30%;
}
```

Comment: poste o código que já fez, para acharmos o erro e corrigir

Comment: @FelipeDuarte coloquei o código

Answer (score 0):

Fique a vontade para estudar [Flexbox css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
figure.cx-fotos-portugal{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: 50vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal img{
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<figure class="cx-fotos-portugal">
    <form>

    </form>
     <img src="https://blog.emania.com.br/content/uploads/2015/12/Papel-de-Parede-de-Paisagem.jpg">
</figure>
```

Comment: Preciso que tenha o elemento `img` e não o background-image

Comment: Editei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Isso porquê você está usando top com %, para obter este efeito com precisão use um tamanho fixo em pixels e ajudando com media query para demais resoluções.

Ou você pode também opinar por colocar um "background: cover", ficando assim:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
figure {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 550px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(imagem);
    background-size: cover;
}

figure form{
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    height: 14%;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 35%;
    top: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar estas medidas no seu CSS:

```
figure.cx-fotos-portugal form {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```